# MVC 4 - Sending Model Data via JSON to Nested Partial Using Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a cshtml page with a partial view. I have an ajax call in that same view retrieving json data based off separate url. I need to pass in the json data into partial. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a controller action taking the view model and passing this view model to the partial view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

and then once you retrieve the JSON data you could invoke this controller action passing the model:

```
// TODO: The JSON data could come from anywhere
var jsonData = { foo: 'bar' };
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    success: function(result) {
        // Now update the partial:
        $('#someId').html(result);
    }    
});
```

Comment: As of right now I am using my ajax post method to retrieve my json data. Is this wrong way? Should I use that in an ajax get method and then pass from get to post and do your way?

Comment: The $.ajax method allows you to set the content type to application/json which is required for sending complex JSON objects.

Comment: In url: property will it automatically know what controller to look in for that Action Method?

Comment: Do you have a basic demo you could zip up and send to me for clarity?

Comment: What is it that is not clear? The Url.Action helper method will generate the url to the controller action you indicate using  your routing setup.